# Python panda merging with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes on the column `artist_title`. However, repeated values may be in both columns. As I'm working with a large data set and large columns, I've simplified the dataframes a bit.

In `df1`, the same `artist_title` can be mentioned as in below example 'J. Balvin - Ay Vamos'.

In `df2`, there can also be multiple values for 'J. Balvin - Ay Vamos'.

If it finds `artist_title` from `df1` in `df2`, then it provides `check_code`. When there are multiple values to return from `df2`, I'd like to have a row copied from `df1` to add the additional `check_code` so that I can view both (all) available codes.

`df1`:

```
channel     ID          artist_title

NOW         301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos
NOW         302         Troye Sivan - Bloom
NOW         303         Christina Milian - Dip It Low
NOW         304         Lorde - Royals
TRENDING    301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos
TRENDING    305         Mase - Welcome Back
CHILL       306         Bastille - Pompeii
```

`df2`:

```
artist_title               check_code

The Doors - Touch Me       AD9823459
Ricky Martin - She Bangs   SD8845623 
Spice Girls - Wannabe      SDF945345
Daft Punk - Da Funk        KI9023475
J. Balvin - Ay Vamos       URY734586
J. Balvin - Ay Vamos       YH4763523
Troye Sivan - Bloom        EH7623495
```

Desired outcome:

```
channel     ID          artist_title                    check_code

NOW         301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            URY734586
NOW         301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            YH4763523
NOW         302         Troye Sivan - Bloom             EH7623495
NOW         303         Christina Milian - Dip It Low   NaN
NOW         304         Lorde - Royals                  NaN
TRENDING    301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            URY734586
TRENDING    301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            YH4763523
TRENDING    305         Mase - Welcome Back             NaN
CHILL       306         Bastille - Pompeii              NaN
```

I tried merging:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='artist_title', how = 'left')
```

The results:

It does create additional rows, but it always contains a 'check_code' from something entirely different and the second one is the correct 'check_code'. For example, something like this:

```
channel     ID          artist_title                    check_code

NOW         301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            ABE000149
NOW         301         J. Balvin - Ay Vamos            YH4763523
```

As both columns contain repeated values, I'm guessing I need to be doing something else than merge? How can I best achieve the above?

Added: `df1` has 4405 values, `df2` has 177806 values. I only want to have the values from `df2` if they are in `df1`. If not, then I don't want them.

Comment: Have you tried using `how='outer'`?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what i want: df1 contains 4405 values (those i want to have merged), df2 contains 177806 values. I don't want any values from df2 that are not mentioned in df1

Comment: So then you can just `dropna` on left only field, such as `channel` or `ID`. (Also, if you make the dataframes copyable, it is easier to test our answers)

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it looks like you might want `df2` as the `left` table in the merge, no? Adding the IDs and whatnot to the existing check codes?

Comment: Ah yes that is true, however, It still doesn't give the right output. It produces a second line for df1, but it matches the wrong code

Comment: @G.Anderson I see your point, but this is also giving me the same wrong output: `NOW         302         Troye Sivan - Bloom` is once in df2. So it should only have one row in output. However, in my output it show it twice, with on the second row `EH7623495` and the first row something completely different. I cannot find out it got the other code from.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a data issue rather than a merge issue. Have you looked at the rows in your DFs where the correct and incorrect IDs and check codes exist?

Comment: @G.Anderson Hmm i feared so, but I cannot find anything weird if I look at the dataframes individually and I can find both values manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dictionary to map with.

```
mapper = {}
def make_map(row):
    mapper[row['artist_title']] = row['check_code']
df2.apply(make_map,axis=1)

df['check_code'] = df['artist_title'].map(mapper)
```

Which should return expected results (removed my results as I messed up when I transferred the info into python and that took forever)

Comment: Ah great! This seems to be working for my dataset, thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. If you like an answer please remember to mark it as the answer :)